# How to fix WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS in intellij on windows

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to run the collaborative filtering version of spark-mllib on my machine using intellij community edition 2018.1 running on windows. I have used the same structure for many other scripts without spark-mllib and everything runs good. I have the problem only when I import spark-mllib library.

the code that I am using is :

```scala
   var okrating = List[Rating]()
   var r = new Random()
    for( u <- 1 to 10){
      for(p <- 1 to 10){
        if(r.nextBoolean()){
          var rt = new Rating(u, p, 5*r.nextDouble())
          okrating = okrating :+ rt
        }
      }
    }
    ratings = sc.parallelize(okrating)
    println(ratings.collect().mkString("\n"))

    val model = ALS.train(ratings, 10, 100, 0.01)
```

the dependencies are :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Current error message:

```
19/06/03 18:04:44 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
19/06/03 18:04:44 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
19/06/03 18:04:45 WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemLAPACK
19/06/03 18:04:45 WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefLAPACK
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 71.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 71.0 (TID 515, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
...
```

Any ideas obout the origin of this error? and how to get ride of it?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI those are warnings, not errors. Your program crashes because of a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: I think that they are related, because it is not normal to have a ```StackOverflowError``` with this size of data.

Comment: It's probably more related to e.g. the size of the execution plan than the size of the data.

Comment: I don't know much of mllib or netlib but I've seen stackoverflows similar to this that were caused by unions of many RDDs (resulting in large execution plans), if I remember correctly.

Comment: I verified the JVM maximmum heap size is 1024MB.

Comment: Heap size and stack size are unrelated. The default stack size is relatively small.

Comment: Finally you were right the problem is the high number of iterations (100), the stack could support only 10 iterations without problem. Thank you.